# OData V4 - return root entity only if expanded property meets certain conditions

Tags: odata, sap-cloud-sdk

I have an OData-V4 Service and I want to output the root entity only if the expand from the expand meets certain conditions. Side note: I'm trying to implement this with the SAP Cloud SDK.

In this example, the root entity with the Product 123456 should only be displayed if /toProductSalesDelivery/toMaterialStatus.BlockedForSalesOrder != B. Is this possible?

I have the following structure:

```
{
  "value" : [
    {
      "Product" : "123456",
      "Assortment" : "DE12",
      "Disabled" : false
      "IsActiveEntity" : true,
      "toProductSalesDelivery" : [
        {
          "Product" : "123456",
          "ProductSalesOrg" : "1000",
          "toMaterialStatus" : [
            {
              "BlockedForSalesOrder" : "B"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My first try was via $expand and $filter. the filter on the navigation property was fulfilled, but that was not what I wanted. Of course I don't want the root entity to be displayed either.... It's just filtering the MaterialStatus array.

```
Product?$select=Assortment,Product&$expand=toProductSalesDelivery($expand=toMaterialStatus($select=BlockedForSalesOrder;$filter=(BlockedForSalesOrder ne 'B')))&$filter=((Disabled eq false))
```

Two hours later and "reading" the docs, I have now the following query. Unfortunately the root entity is still displayed.

```
Assortment_Product?$filter=toProductSalesDelivery/any(d:d/toMaterialStatus/any(m:m/BlockedForSalesOrder eq 'B'))
&$expand=toProductSalesDelivery($expand=toMaterialStatus)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Are you using Java or JavaScript version of the SAP Cloud SDK?

Comment: I'm usin Java, but we have already opened a ticket. The SDK is assembling the URL incorrectly. The framework always uses the same variable for the lambda operations. That's probably why it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [fixed with version 4.22.0](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes#fixed-issues) of the SAP Cloud SDK. Nesting lambdas is now possible.